# How to tell Facebook to remove Javascript cache

Tags: javascript, facebook, caching

So, i m working on a facebook app. It has javsacript.  Of course, FB will sanitize the javascript. Of course, FB cache the javascript. 
Whenever I upload the js file, it takes a while or a long while for the new javascript to take affect.

That's annoying for development. :(

so, anyone know how to notify FB (vai API or some FB js call) to refresh the cache or take the javascript & replace the one in the cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to append a modifier to the end of the call to trick their cache into thinking it's a new file.  (You can use an internal version number or the unix epoch time of its last modification, for example)

file.js?mod=12345

Answer (score -3):

Use the [Firefox plugin Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) and there [disable caching](http://tips.webdesign10.com/web-developer-toolbar.htm) in your browser!

If you really want FB to refresh your JS files, you have to rename them every time you change something.

Comment: This is a Facebook platform specific issue, the caching is done server-side on their part.

Comment: This ia not client side issue. :)  
Thanks Brad.